# Proof of characterization of positive zeros of linear map using linear programming

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

Prove that for every matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ precisely one of the following statements is true:

a) $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}^n: (Ax = 0 \wedge x > 0)$, where $x > 0$ means that all components of $x$ are strictly positive,

b) $\exists y \in \mathbb{R}^m: (A^Ty \geq 0 \wedge A^Ty \neq 0)$

This should be proven using linear programming.

I have proved that if a) holds than b) cannot hold. I proved this in the following way:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. We define $n$ different linear programs with linear form $f_i(x) = \langle \varepsilon e_i, x \rangle$, where $e_i$ is the $i$-th unit vector ($i$-th coordinate is $1$, others are $0$), and constraints $Ax = 0, x \geq 0$. We are maximizing the linear forms. Then the dual of each of these linear programs is a minimising linear program with constant linear form that is equal to zero and constraints $A^Ty \geq \varepsilon e_i$. If we assume that a) holds, all of the starting linear programs are unbounded because all multiples of $x$ from the statement a) are feasible solutions. That means that all duals are infeasible (this follows from weak duality theorem) which means that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is no $y$ such that $A^Ty \geq \varepsilon e_i$. This means that there is no $y$ such $A^Ty \geq 0$ and $A^Ty \neq 0$, so b) doesn't hold.

However I don't know how to prove that a) holds if b) doesn't hold. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $y$ is not used in statement (b). Is there a typo? Anyway, this is reminiscent of [Farkas’ lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma). So, the ideas in its proofs may help.

Comment: @user1551 Yes it's a typo and I have fixed it. I know Farkas' lemma and I have used ideas from it's proof to prove what I have already proved. I don't know how to help myself with Farkas' lemma any further.

Comment: The conditions (a) and (b) cannot hold simultaneously. Indeed,
assume $A^Ty\ge 0$ and $Ax=0$ for some $x>0.$ Then
$$0=\langle Ax, y\rangle =\langle x, A^Ty\rangle $$
Since $x>0$ and $A^Ty\ge 0,$ we conclude that $A^Ty=0.$
The main problem is that if one condition does not hold the other holds. For this you should apply linear programming methods.

Comment: Oh that's right, my bad, I messed up with elementary logic. Thank you, I will fix the question.